# How do I configure an Azure WebJob to connect with single IP to FTPS?

Tags: azure, ftps

I want to connect to a secure FTP server (FTPS, not SFTP) from an Azure WebJob (basically an Azure Web App instance).

In order to do a secure file transfer, the same SSL session must be reused for the control and data channel. However, the server (FileZilla Server) can be configured to allow different SSL sessions (less secure, vulnerable to someone stealing the data channel session).

However, I still get the error
`425 Rejected data connection for transfer of "/myfolder", IP addresses of control and data connection do not match` **because Azure uses several different outbound IP addresses** and when running several downloads in parallell, this error occurs.

I understand why the error occurs, but can I somehow work around it by telling Azure to only use 1 outbound IP address?

Comment: Did you check out the new App service environments? There you can have control over outbound IP address. Please check this- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-network-architecture-overview/

Comment: @GandhaliSamant No, not with this use case in mind. Thanks, I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Marcus Honestly I can't remember exactly, but I think we ended up modifying the FTPS configuration.